# Snowflake Self Service Role Automation

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Has anyone implemented a process whereby a user can submit a request for a role and that role will, after approval, be granted to that user?

So something like user fills out request form, once submitted an email is sent for approval, once approved a process is kicked off to run the grant statement and email the user that they have been granted a role.

In addition I would want that transaction logged for auditing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your list of users/roles/grants on a version controlled file - and use commits to that file as a trigger to change Snowflake's configuration.

That's basically what tools like Terraform and Permifrost do.

See this discussion from dbt users:

- https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/how-do-you-manage-snowflake-privileges/1397/4

This is a guide for Terraform on Snowflake:

- https://guides.snowflake.com/guide/terraforming_snowflake/index.html

Meanwhile Permifrost:

> Usage: permifrost run [OPTIONS] SPEC
>
> Grant the permissions provided in the provided specification file for
> specific users and roles

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-data/permifrost/